# Fitting image in lay-out android project

Tags: android, image

I have added a transparent picture in my layout. Now that it's transparent, the sizing is kind of different. It has some space above the image, while I want it to be completely on top. It's about the image in the top left of the screen, the bar with the colors.
Above that bar, there is some open space. I want that bar to be completely in the top left, leaving no open space between the bar and top ending of the screen.

Unfortunately i have no idea how to do this. I've changed the size of the image, but that won't help. Does anyone of you have an idea?

This is the image I'm talking about :

[image]

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is my xml code. the Imageview with drawable/logoversiejuni is the part with the logo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/atrium">


   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logoversiejuni" />

 </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bezoektijdenbutton"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

          <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/routebutton"
            android:text="Route" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/meningbutton"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/vriendenbutton"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/foldersbutton"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/specialistenbutton"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bwcbutton"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/nieuwsbutton"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the code. What have you done so far ?

Comment: my bad for not posting the code. It's the code with the : drawable/logoversiejuni that i'm talking about. Changed all the sizes, just the space above it is the point idk anyhting about

Comment: If there is any transparent space in the image then remove it{use photoshop} change the height attribute to wrapContent and set scaleType to FitCenter and you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using FrameLayout use RelativeLayout and align the view to the top. Also set `ImageView` scale type to `fitStart`. Something like this:

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/logoversiejuni" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This removes the space on top, but makes it huge, and in the middle of the screen. I can deal with the sizes, but the image needs to be in the top left of the screen

Comment: It means that logoversiejuni is a large image. Try setting it's size equal to the other imageview i.e imageButton1

Comment: The sizing is correct now. It's also in the top left of the screen. However, all the buttons under it are placed more downwards. Some are under the screen, not even visible anymore. Do you know how to place them more upwards where they were?

Comment: You can try reducing the top margins of the LinearLayout containing the bottom buttons.

Comment: Changed it to 0dp. Found out that the image size is just too big. The image is shown in the top, but has a lot of space under it, which is still part of the image.. Do you know how to reduce that bottom size of the image?

Comment: Fixed it, just an height change. Thanks !

Comment: Is that space part of the source image? You have to crop it our manually, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logoversiejuni" />
```